# Center-aligning without using HTML tables

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I'm trying to make `div` elements align down the middle (between two images) without using tables (because tables shouldn't be used for styling/layout).

I have the following individual elements:

### img

[image: first logo]

### img

[image: second logo]

### div

[image: rounded DIV]

And I want the final output, using CSS, to be:

[image: final output]

Seems simple, right? Well, the **trick is that the scores to the left and right of the images are variable width**, and I want the center of the rounded rectangle to slice right between the two images, regardless of the widths of the score values. (Thus, I can't just wrap a div around the whole block and use `text-align: center`. Would do me no good.)

As you can see in my example pic, there is more space between the edge of the rectangle and the score on the right than there is on the left, because the left score itself is wider.

Also note that the images expand slightly above and below the rectangle div, which is another reason why using a table wouldn't be ideal.

I've tried to accomplish this layout using combinations of `margin-left: auto`, `margin-right: auto`, `display: inline-block`, etc., but I can't get the centered effect I'm looking for.

[Here is a jsfiddle to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/DzXUh/6/)

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A Jsfiddle or similar thing would make it easy for people to experiment and try to create a solution

Comment: Here's a starting point fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/DzXUh/

Comment: @acjohnson55 See edits, added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the deal:

- `.team` should have `width: 50%` and should be floated left. Or right. Whatever.
- The images should be floated toward the center. The one on the left should be floated right, the one on the right should be floated left.
- The images should also have `position: relative` and a negative `top`.
- `.team` should also have `text-align` set. The one on left should have `text-align: right`
- The outer container should have `overflow` set to `visible` (which is the default - I just wanted to mention it because other answers told you to use `overflow: hidden`. Which would break your "outside the box" stuff).

That should get you what you want. [And here's proof](http://jsfiddle.net/33XQ7/) (started before you posted your fiddle)

Comment: Looks promising! Made a few tweaks and got this, which is pretty darn close to my desired result: http://jsfiddle.net/33XQ7/1/

Comment: Sweet! Spend a bit more time on it, and I think you got it.

Comment: Well, I ran into a snag when you try to add more than one game. The vertical alignment of the images and scores stops lining up with the rounded background: http://jsfiddle.net/33XQ7/2/ . Thoughts?

Comment: OK, looks like all I needed to do was increase the `margin-top` of the `.game` div!

Answer (score 0):

UI elements (things that are not content) should be CSS backgrounds. Make a composite image and make it the background for a wrapping DIV, then make two inside it - one floated left, the other floated right and with a bit of margin and padding everything will work just fine.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="scoreLeft"></div>
   <div class="scoreRight"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: See the jsfiddle link I added to my original question. The issue is more complicated than your answer, it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

All of the inner child elements of your `div` should have `float: left`. Then, the parent `div` should have `overflow: hidden`. From there, you can then add additional `margin`'s to the `div img` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example solution.  The idea is that you have a wrapper do the grey background and size the bar.  You than have a div half the size and align the text towards the center while putting enough padding to allow for background images.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="scoreLeft">1231231</div>
   <div class="scoreRight">123</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  background: grey;
  background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fkZv.png');
  background-size:400px 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  display: table; //Allow for vertical align
  table-layout: fixed;  //Allow for fixed widths of children
}
.scoreLeft, .scoreRight {
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;  //Allow for vertical align
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;  //Allow for 50% width with padding sitting inside the 50%.  This can be mathed out so the width + padding * 2 = wrapper width and then you can use the default box-sizing.
}
.scoreLeft {
  background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmWiD.png');
  background-size:50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:right;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 55px;
}
.scoreRight {
  background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkll9.png');
  background-size:50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 55px;
}
```